# getApplition() not return application instance

Tags: android, dagger-2

In manifest file, I set:

```
<application  android:name=".MyApplication" />
```

But in activity when I call:

```
getApplication()
```

it returns android.app.Application instance not MyApplication instance.
I think it causes by I am using Dagger2. I am new to dagger2

Comment: I think android:name=".MyApplication" not working

Comment: What do you mean "it" returns `Application`? Are you talking about the method signature or have you debugged it at Runtime and either examined the object with introspection or failed to cast it to your `MyApplication ` class?

Comment: Also make sure that the package matches the short hand you are using

Answer (score 0):

The better way to access to application instance — property in your Application class.
Java example:

```
class App extends Application {

   private static App instance;

   @Override
   public void onAttachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
      super.onAttachBaseContext(newBase);
      this.instance = this;
   }

   public static App getInstance() {
      return this.instance;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyApplication` is a child class of `android.app.Application`, [getApplication()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication()) returns it as an `Application` instance, but it is actually your class. That's use of inheritance. You need to process it further, by

```
MyApplication myApp = null;

Application app = getApplication();
if (app instanceOf MyApplication) {
    myApp = (MyApplication) app;
}
```

or you can simply do

```
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```